# Jquery - How to display images using their physical path

Tags: jquery

How can is specify physical path of the image in src attribute. When ever i pass physical path to image it does not display. any hint or help will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you're giving it the right path? How are you setting the path? Show us some code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.It would be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newPhoto = new Image();
  newPhoto.src = '/home/user/image.jpg'; // absolute path
  $('h1').hover({
   function() {
     $('#photo').attr('src', newPhoto.src);
   }
  })
});
```

This is assuming you're loading the image on a `hover` trigger and the image tag is inside a `h1` tag.